# Mercurial version control not working properly

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have just install Mercurial on CentOS and followed the tutorial here

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TutorialInit

I created hello.txt in folder called mercury i.e

```
/home/user/mercury/hello.txt
```

Then i did

```
hg commit -m "adding initial version of hello.txt"
```

Accoring to Docs it should create a folder called my-hello but thats not created

What can be the problem

Comment: No it shouldn't - where in  the docs does it say that? And have you done an `hg init` and `hg add`?

Comment: It does indeed say that in the linked article.

Comment: So it does! Well, it is wrong! and in fact, the sample terminal session illustrates this.

Comment: I have updated the tutorial Wiki to remove the my-hello sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last sentence or so of the tutorial is wrong. It should really say something like:

"Nothing obvious changes about the files now that they've been committed, but this version of our files is preserved in the repository. We can confirm this by typing `hg log` which will show the revision"

Comment: what will ahppen if i edit my files hello.txt via vi editor and not commit it. Do it still have new contents or i have to hg commit it to save. i am new to version control

Comment: You will have uncommitted changes. The repository is only updated when you do a commit. You should do a commit after each significant change, where you are happy with the results.

Comment: what do u mean by results , if chnages r not commited , how can i check the result . suppose i have file backup.sh which is working ok . then i do chnage via vi but without commit. now if i then execute ./backup.sh will it do old stuff or with new changes.

Comment: But all subsequent tutorial say to go to `my-hello` repo whichis not there as you said. what should i do  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialFirstChange

Comment: @bidu Yes, that tutorial has got completely screwed up somehow - links are pointing to different pages at the beginnning and end of the page. There are other tutorials - for example Joels at http://hginit.com and the introductory chapter from the Mercurial book at http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html. If you want to stick with the wiki tutorial, take it from this page http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialClone.

Comment: @bidu When you read the files on disk, or execute them (if they are scripts or programs) you of course read the current contents of the file. So if you edit the file, and save, and then execute it, you'll execute the new version of the script. However, the Mercurial repository has not been told that you have changed the file yet, for that you need to execute a commit command. The "working directory" is where you work on the files, and then you use commit to commit those changes into the repository. Did that make it clearer?

Comment: @Lasse thanks, so it means working directory is different from repository. Actually in my case it was same. Can working directory be on my windows computer and repo be my live sites www folder